How to deploy openstack with SFC and heat templates?
I'm working on project that using openstack.
In my project, I want to enable Service chainging (SFC), in order to chain my Firewall gateway in the traffic flow.
Also, I want to automate the deploy process with heat teamplate.
Currently, I have my dedicated server, with Ubuntu desktop 22.04. It connected to public network and I use Bridge-interface as guided here
I managed to install the base Devstack, that guided here but now, I want to enable SFC and heat.
For Heat, as far I understand, from Heat and Devstack I add in local.conf the next line
enable_service h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw

also, for SFC, as far I understand from SFC repo
I add in local.conf the next line:
enable_plugin networking-sfc /opt/stack/networking-sfc

Now, I run stack.sh and it finish.
For SFC:
when I run openstack extension list --network I see the line
| Service Function Chaining                                                                  | sfc                                         | Service Function Chain extension.                                                           |

So I think it enabled
For the Heat:
I don't see in the dashboard the orchestration UI. also, when I looking for stack.sh.log and search for the h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw, I notice for the next lines:
cat stack.sh.log | grep "h-api"
2024-11-13 22:43:22.732 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1715      (B[m for service in ${ENABLED_SERVICES//,/ }
2024-11-13 22:43:22.747 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1717      (B[m sudo systemctl is-enabled devstack@h-eng.service
2024-11-13 22:43:22.774 | Failed to get unit file state for devstack@h-eng.service: No such file or directory
2024-11-13 22:43:22.793 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1715      (B[m for service in ${ENABLED_SERVICES//,/ }
2024-11-13 22:43:22.809 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1717      (B[m sudo systemctl is-enabled devstack@h-api.service
2024-11-13 22:43:22.835 | Failed to get unit file state for devstack@h-api.service: No such file or directory
2024-11-13 22:43:22.854 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1715      (B[m for service in ${ENABLED_SERVICES//,/ }
2024-11-13 22:43:22.870 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1717      (B[m sudo systemctl is-enabled devstack@h-api-cfn.service
2024-11-13 22:43:22.896 | Failed to get unit file state for devstack@h-api-cfn.service: No such file or directory
2024-11-13 22:43:22.915 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1715      (B[m for service in ${ENABLED_SERVICES//,/ }
2024-11-13 22:43:22.931 | +[38;5;242mfunctions-common:service_check:1717      (B[m sudo systemctl is-enabled devstack@h-api-cw.service
2024-11-13 22:43:22.955 | Failed to get unit file state for devstack@h-api-cw.service: No such file or directory

So I think the Heat installation dont works.
1. Is Heat and SFC are supported in Devstack deploy?
2. It possible to install/enable/deploy only the heat without run stack.sh (or worse: unstack.sh , clean.sh and stack.sh again?
Now I'm stuck and any help will be great.
I try to run the installation without SFC and heat, and that works.
Then, I edit local.conf and run stack.sh again and my env break (It made conectivity issues)
Also, I already try to deploy Openstack with snap microstack and with sunbeam project to make my life easier, but then I notice sunbeam use OVN as network provider that does not support SFC and supporting SFC with OVN not planned (I need OVS network provider to support SFC).  So I try to deploy with DevStack, since it seems OVS used as default
